# Refer to folders using /dev/sd#/*

Tags: fstab

Can we bind folders with their directories described with the drive names? For example:

```
/dev/sda1/Folder
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: @jo-erlend, in a particular case, mounting a partition with either UUID or label failed. The partition is one the same device as `/`, so it is mounted automatically. If `/dev/sd*` works, then I don't need to make a mount entry for it in `fstab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. `/dev/sd*` are devices. But you can always mount your partition automatically by placing a line like this one below in your `fstab` and using its `/dev/sd*` name:

```
/dev/sda4    /media/sda4    [... options ...]
```

And referring to your reply to jo-erlend:

> "in a particular case, mounting a partition with either UUID or label failed. The partition is one the same device as /, so it is mounted automatically."

I assume that you meant 'The partition is **on** the same device ...', right? It is not mounted automatically. '/' is mounted because it has its own line in `fstab` file.

uuid files (located in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`) are just links to their associated `/dev/sd*` files. So it is very much likely that if mount fails with uuid, so it will using `/dev/sd*`.

Comment: You are right, I meant that the partition is automatically mounted because it's on the same device as `/`. But if the mount by `fstab` is failing, what do you suggest I do? UUID is out of the question anyway, because the operating system is on a USB, and it changes if I plug it into other PCs.

Comment: Can you tell us why is it failing? Any error messages or something? If the OS is on a USB, then the USB itself will be `/dev/sda`, and its partitions are `/dev/sda#`. If I get it right, you want to automatically mount a partition that is on this USB. Just add a line for it in the `fstab`. If you tell me its `/dev/sd#` name and filesystem type, I can write this line for you.

Comment: This is what I used to bypass UUID's potential inconsistency: `LABEL=”NTFS” /media/NTFS ntfs defaults 0 0`

Comment: Of course I labelled it as such before making the `fstab` entry. The error message was shown under neath the four dots loading image of Ubuntu and said the folders to be bound were not found.

Comment: Why don't you use `/dev/sd#` instead of `LABEL="NTFS"`?

Comment: I wasn't aware I could do that, dammit! Thanks! I'll try it out and get back at you.

Answer (score 2):

No. /dev/sda1 is a partition. The partition contains a filesystem which you'll mount. But you can mount them anywhere you like. Nothing really wrong if you want to use /partitions/sda1 instead of /media/hollidays-2011 for instance, but I don't understand why you'd want to.

Comment: Also, if not under `/media` it will not show on desktop.

Comment: See the reply to your comment.

Comment: You always have to mount the filesystem, but you don't have to use an UUID if you don't want to. You can use the device name in /etc/fstab or using the mount command.